# Javascript - Load HTML page into another page using attributes without using object, I want it directly inside my page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey I'm trying to load a simple HTML component into my main-page.
A single component should represent a Game-Entry, I used to load them using:

```
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>



<div w3-include-html="./components/GameComponent.html"></div>
<script>w3IncludeHTML();</script>
```

Now im trying to recreate it using Javascript, im loading the data from the local storage, this worked fine so far, but when im trying to recreate the structure it doesnt really load the HTML of the component.

My current Javascript script looks like this:

```
let gamesNode = document.getElementById("games");

for (let i=0; i<loadedGames.length; i++){

    let game = document.createElement("div");
    game.setAttribute("w3-include-html","components/GameComponent.html");
    
    gamesNode.appendChild(game);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to run **w3IncludeHTML();** after updating the DOM node